# Create a correct PKCS7/CMS (ASN.1) from existing XML Signature in PHP

Tags: php, pki, asn.1, pkcs#7, xml-dsig

I have an XML digital signature, (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig`) and I want to convert this into a PKCS7 signature.

I belive I have to use an ASN.1 encoder such as https://github.com/FGrosse/PHPASN1 but I cannot understand how to create a valid pkcs7/asn.1 signaure with it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not posible.

When making a XML signature, the private key is signing a data codification (codified in XML).

You are able to put the information included in this XML signature into a PKCS7 signature (codified in ASN.1).
But then, the codification of these data would be different, so the signature wouldn't be valid.